# VBA: Select cells in column, copy multiple cells from the selected cells´ rows and copy into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to create a macro (and searched Google for what feels like forever), but did still not resolve my issue, where I can select one or multiple cells in e.g. column A and run the macro. Then the macro should copy paste data from several cells within the selected cells´ rows to specific cells in another workbook. I hope it makes sense so far.

Anyhow, here is an example:
If I select `A1`, `A2`, `A4` and run the macro, the follow cells should be copied to a new workbook:

```
A1, A2, A4 --> B1, B2, B4
F1, F2, F4 --> D1, D2, D4
E1, E2, E4 --> F1, F2, F4
etc. so I can edit/change it depending on my need.
```

If it is possible, I would actually like the pasted data to start in row 13.
I would appreciate if the code could be commented, so I can learn more about it :)

**SOLVED IT**
*** UPDATE ***

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wkbCurrent, wkbNew As Workbook
Set wkbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Dim valg, c, LastCell As Range
Set valg = Selection
Dim wkbPath, wkbFileName, lastRow As String
Dim LastRowInput As Long
Dim lrow, rwCount As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo errHandler

wkbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
wkbFileName = Dir(wkbPath & "CIF LISTEN.xlsm")

Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Open(wkbPath & "CIF LISTEN.xlsm")

LastRowInput = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

' If nothing is selected in column A
' GoTo Error Handling
If valg.Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then
    GoTo errHandler
End If

For Each c In valg.Cells
    lrow = wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Offset(wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & lrow)
    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & lrow)
    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("F" & lrow)
Next

'Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & Selection.Rows.count & " Suppliers Added"

' wkbNew.Close False
' wkbfilename = Dir

' Find the number of rows that is copied over
wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Activate
areaCount = Selection.Areas.count
If areaCount <= 1 Then
    MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Rows.count & " suppliers."
    ' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
    wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & Selection.Rows.count & " Suppliers Added"
Else
    I = 1
    For Each a In Selection.Areas
        'MsgBox "Area " & I & " of the selection contains " & _
        a.Rows.count & " rows."
        I = I + 1
        rwCount = rwCount + a.Rows.count
    Next a
    MsgBox "The selection contains " & rwCount & " suppliers."
    ' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
    wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & rwCount & " Suppliers Added"
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Error Handling
exitHandler:
wkbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Please select cell(s) in column A", vbCritical, "Error"
Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I added this code. It is now working for me to transfer my data from my sheet to another new workbook. However, I already have a workbook with a certain format/laylout that I would like the data to be pasted into. Is it also possible that every time I run the macro, it will be posted below the inputs? Can you help me?

Comment: Is the range you want to search always column A? Also, will the range be non-contiguous? It is preferable to not use `Selection` when possible.

Comment: Yeah. So I want to select the company names in my column and then the macro copy pastes these specific cells of data into another sheet that is already existing (file name is "CIF LISTEN.xlsm"). I have a big master data file with all the data, so basically, I want to be able to pull the data from the company names that mark (select) and then copy it into another workbook.

Comment: So I updated my code. Now I can open and post to the workbook that I want. However, I want it to post it under the last row, can you help Kyle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**
*** UPDATE ***

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wkbCurrent, wkbNew As Workbook
Set wkbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Dim valg, c, LastCell As Range
Set valg = Selection
Dim wkbPath, wkbFileName, lastRow As String
Dim LastRowInput As Long
Dim lrow, rwCount As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo errHandler

wkbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
wkbFileName = Dir(wkbPath & "CIF LISTEN.xlsm")

Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Open(wkbPath & "CIF LISTEN.xlsm")

LastRowInput = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

' If nothing is selected in column A
' GoTo Error Handling
If valg.Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then
GoTo errHandler
End If

For Each c In valg.Cells
lrow = wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Offset(wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & lrow)
    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & lrow)
    wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & c.Row).Copy Destination:=wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("F" & lrow)
Next

'Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & Selection.Rows.count & " Suppliers Added"

' wkbNew.Close False
' wkbfilename = Dir

' Find the number of rows that is copied over
wkbCurrent.ActiveSheet.Activate
areaCount = Selection.Areas.count
If areaCount <= 1 Then
MsgBox "The selection contains " & Selection.Rows.count & " suppliers."
' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & Selection.Rows.count & " Suppliers Added"
Else
I = 1
 For Each a In Selection.Areas
 'MsgBox "Area " & I & " of the selection contains " & _
 a.Rows.count & " rows."
I = I + 1
rwCount = rwCount + a.Rows.count
Next a
MsgBox "The selection contains " & rwCount & " suppliers."
' Write it in A10 in CIF LISTEN
wkbNew.Worksheets(1).Range("A10").Value = "COMMENTS: " & rwCount & " Suppliers Added"
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Error Handling
exitHandler:
wkbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Please select cell(s) in column A", vbCritical, "Error"
Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to vba too and the following is my attempt

```
Sub Main()

'Decoration of selected range
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Set rngCopy = Selection
'Get Column number for selected range
    Dim n As Integer
    n = ActiveCell.Column

'Control which column to paste the data
    If n = 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        rngCopy.Copy

        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add     'Create new workbook
        Cells(13, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    ElseIf n = 2 Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        rngCopy.Copy

        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        Cells(13, 4).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    ElseIf n = 3 Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        rngCopy.Copy

        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        Cells(13, 6).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Else
        MsgBox "Please advise which column i should paste in the code"

    End If

End Sub
```

It is not a elegant code, and you need to fine tune the code where to paste the code. For example if selected column number is 1 (column A) then needa paste to column 2 (column B) for new workbook.

Comment: Hi useR, I appreciate your input, however, it didn´t really work in the way that I wanted, so I decided to try go to for another approach. See my code above.